OR in LDAP filter not working as expected
I'm using Authentik's LDAP provider and am trying to create a filter which returns both users and groups. This lead me to the following filter:
(|(objectClass=posixAccount)(objectClass=posixGroup))
However this query only returns posixGroups. But when I use the following filter:
(|(objectClass=posixGroup)(objectClass=posixAccount))
only posixAccounts are returned.
I thought this or operation was supposed to actually act as an or. So either I'm really missing something or there's an issue with Authentik's LDAP implementation.
Additional context: objectClass in this case (and I believe most implementations) is an attribute which appears multiple times, so maybe there's something I'm missing there.

I am facing the same issue. I have ran the same filters against a SAMBA LDAP just to check that I was not going insane. Your filter is correct, Authentik's LDAP outpost seems to have a bug. The bug is reported here: https://github.com/goauthentik/authentik/issues/11880
